# Connecting to Facebook's API

Tags: facebook, api, authentication, token, httr

I am facing this issue connecting with Facebook's API using httr package, while testing on 'me' node I came along the following problem.
I was under the impression that me node does not require special permissions.
Testing on the browser with 'https://graph.facebook.com/me' gave the same results, it would be great if  some one could provide an explanation.

```
# Define keys
app_id = 'my_app_id'
app_secret = 'my_app_secret'

# Define the app
fb_app <- oauth_app(appname = "facebook",
                    key = app_id,
                    secret = app_secret)

# Get OAuth user access token
fb_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("facebook"),
                           fb_app,
                           scope = 'public_profile',
                           type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                           cache = TRUE)

response <- GET("https://graph.facebook.com",
                path = "/me",
                config = config(token = fb_token))
```

```
# Show content returned
content(response)

$error
$error$message
[1] "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

$error$type
[1] "OAuthException"

$error$code
[1] 2500

$error$fbtrace_id
[1] "ARRnb93rZHmWLlXK_MMJlfi"
```

Noting that I have signed in using the app.

Comment: You of course need to pass in an access token. Otherwise Facebook have no idea who me is

Comment: @WizKid doesn't the parameter token in the config function take care of that?
If not, how do I pass an access token?